# cambio de tipografia

Tags: css, bootstrap

soy una estudiante de diseño web, tenemos un proyecto sobre una tienda de vinos. El problema es cuando incluyo el bootstrap.min.css (estoy usando bootstrap 4.1.1) me cambia toda la tipografia y realmente no sé donde debo hacer los cambios, necesito ayuda en serio! :'(

Comment: Hola Sammy, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so] por favor termina el [tour] y revisa [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas y obtengas respuestas de calidad. Por lo general las preguntas obtienen respuestas efectivas cuando se incluye un [mcve]

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal, Bootstrap usa Helvetica como fuente. Puedes abrir el fichero y ver dónde se pone esa fuente, de ese modo sabrás qué reglas debes cambiar para solucionar los problemas con la fuente.

Comment: Si pones en vez de bootstrap.min el archivo sin el min. te sera mas facil de ver en que clases cambiar la letra.

Answer (score 1):

Abre el archivo bootstrap.css (no el min.css) y ahí tendrás todo el CSS legible.

Una vez alli buscas: **Font-Family** y lo cambias por la fuente que quieras. Muchas fuentes puedes encontrarlas en https://fonts.google.com/

Otra forma más conveniente sino, para no tocar el CSS original, sería que crees tu CSS, llames a ese archivo desde tu arhivo HTML y listo y tu agregues la línea de CSS que corresponde para cambiar la tipografía.

Te dejo una web con más info:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp